# Return value from a subroutine in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, subroutine

I'm writing a simple program that calls a subroutine and expects a value back. so far I have:

```
%include "asm_io.inc"
SECTION .data
SECTION .bss
SECTION .text
    global asm_main
asm_main: 
enter 0,0
pusha 
mov ebx, dword [ebp+12]
mov eax, dword [ebx+4]
push eax
call maxLyn
push eax        ; contains value 4
call print_int
popa
leave 
ret

maxLyn:
enter 0,0
pusha
mov ebx, dword[ebp+12]
mov eax, [ebx+4]
add eax, dword 2
push eax
ret
```

So when I run code `lynarr abc 2`, I'm expecting a value of 4 to be displayed. But it's not showing any results. any ideas would be really helpful!

Comment: Also you pushed Eax before ret. Your return address is lost. Not to mention pusha. When you call a subroutine, return address is on the top of the stack. You need to keep it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Since you're calling your program with "lynarr abc 2" to get a pointer to the 2nd commandline argument you need to use `mov ebx, dword [ebp+12]`  `mov eax, dword [ebx+8]`
- Your call to *maxLyn* has only 1 argument. It can be found at [EBP+8]. You wrote [EBP+12].
- You can't use push before the return. Use `leave`
- Don't use `pusha` here. Just push/pop EBX.
- Why do you use *print_int* when AL/EAX contains a character "4"

maxLyn becomes:

```
enter 0,0
push  ebx
mov   ebx, dword [ebp+8]
movzx eax, byte [ebx]   ;Character "2"
add   eax, dword 2
pop   ebx
leave
ret
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but I'm getting an error "unary operator expected" after running `lynarr abc 2`

Comment: @Sally unary operator expected sounds like a shell script problem. Are you running your program from a bash script?

Comment: @MichaelPetch yes. here's the full error code `-bash: lynarr: abc: unary operator expected`.

Comment: @Sally That's not a problem in your _C_ program that is a problem in your shell script so that is something completely separate from this question.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I don't know much about that, maybe you're right. Here's what I was doing: I have a file lynarr.asm and I am compiling it using
`nasm -f elf32 lynarr.asm`
`nasm -f elf32 -d ELF_TYPE asm_io.asm`
`gcc -m32 -o lynarr lynarr.o driver.c asm_io.o`
I'm not sure but can you advise any resources where I should be looking?

Comment: @Sally: Use `type -a lynarr` to find out which `lynarr` executable is running.  It's probably not the one in the current directory, unless your `$PATH` includes `.` (the current directory).  Try running `./lynarr abc 2`  If it's running a shell script, then try using `strace -f -eexecve ./lynarr abc 2` to find out what it's running.

Comment: @MichaelPetch  Thank you so much for the help. I read a few books on this topic and I can see where I was making the mistakes. Happy holidays and Merry Christmas ! :-)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you so much for the help. I read a few books on this topic and I can see where I was making the mistakes. Happy holidays and Merry Christmas ! :-)